# Unmangling C++ names on Mac 10.5

Tags: macos, c++filt

I'm printing out the stack trace in my app at various points to debug a problem, which works fine except that the symbol names of my c++ functions are still mangled. On linux I use c++filt to convert them to something more readable... on mac... it doesn't work?!?!

```
macbook:matthew$ c++filt _ZN10GSemaphore6UnlockEv
_ZN10GSemaphore6UnlockEv
```

Even the example supplied in the man page doesn't work. What gives?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
~:1684$ c++filt -n _ZN10GSemaphore6UnlockEv
GSemaphore::Unlock()
```

Comment: Interestingly if I exec(...) enough, c++flit stops returning anything, but that appears to be another issue. Thx.